# Double Printing using ZPL

Tags: printing, double, zpl

I have the task of getting our retail system to print barcode labels on a roll of 1 1/4" by 1" side by side labels. The same information will print on both, but I cannot find a way to print it on the second label. Is there a command/setting that would allow me to feed the data twice, once for each label? Thank you in advance.

Comment: To give directions, we need to know where you're starting from and you haven't told us that. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? Source code helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can just set the print width to the width of both labels side by side and then just position the fields properly for each label by changing the `X,Y` coordinates of the `^FO` or `^FT` command.

```
e.g.

^XA
^A0N50,50^FO100,100^FDText on left label^FS
^A0N50,50^FO500,100^FDText on right label^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to print the same label several times.

I solved this way

```
^XA
^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDLabel 1^FS
^XZ
^XA
^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDLabel 2^FS
^XZ
```

I hope this helps.